# Class number of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{13})$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory

Let $F = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{13})$. Then its ring of integers is $\mathcal{O}_F = \mathbb{Z}\left [\frac{1 + \sqrt{13}}{2}\right ]$.

I am trying to find the class number of $F$.

$F$ has signature $(r,s) = (2,0)$, discriminant $\Delta_F = 13$, and degree $[F: \mathbb{Q}] = 2$.

Hence, by Minkowski's bound for ideal classes, each ideal class $C \in Cl_F$ contains an ideal $I \subseteq \mathcal{O}_F$ with absolute norm satisfying: $$ N(I) \leq \left ( \frac{4}{\pi} \right )^s \frac{n!}{n^n} \sqrt{| \Delta_F |}$$ Hence, with our example, we get $$N(I) < 2$$ and there is no prime less than $2$, so how do I find the generators for the class group now? The generators of the class group are of the form $[P]$, where $P$ is a prime ideal lying above $p$, where $p$ is a prime satisfying $p < 2$. But there is no such prime? So what can I deduce now?

I assume that this shows that the class group is trivial, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: You can deduce that the only ideal in the class group is the (class of the) ideal generated by $1$.

Comment: There is no *positive* prime $p$ satisfying $p < 2$, but since the ideals take care of signs (e.g., $-2 \in \langle 2 \rangle$), you don't really have to worry about that for this.